# Squash commits in interactive rebase with number sign (hash sign)

Tags: git, rebase

we use TFS with Git implementation as our source control. If commit messages include Backlog Item IDs starting with the number sign (like `#1234`) TFS is linking this commit directly with this item.

For the commit message writing, there is no problem, the commit message appears correctly in the log. Since I wrote a git-hook, the item number is set in every commit.

[image]

The problem appears when I use git's **interactive rebase**. I want to squash some commits, but in the editor, the number sign is interpreted as a **Comment sign**.

This is how it looks like:

```
# This is a combination of 4 commits.                                                                                                                            # This is the 1st commit message: 

#1234 Commit Message 1

# This is the commit message #2: 

#1234 some coding here

# This is the commit message #3: 

#1234 just a fix

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting                                                                                               # with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit. 
.
.
.
```

I tried with a backslash so far, but it doesn't work. The Backslash appeared then in the message itself (`\#1234 Commit Message 1`)

Any suggestions, how I could squash my commits while keeping the number sign? Same problem in changing commit message text too.

Comment: This certainly does not look like the interactive rebase window with which I'm familiar, which would start each line with `pick`, `edit`, etc.  Where are you seeing this window?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen they replaced some `pick`s with `squash`, Git did its thing, and now they have a squash commit whose commit *messages* read `#this` and `#that`.

Comment: I got you @torek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set `core.commentChar` to some character other than `#` so that you can use `#` as commit text, instead of as a comment.

You can set this just for the duration of the one rebase:

```
git -c core.commentchar=: rebase -i ...
```

for instance.  But if you are going to do this often, you might want to use `git config` to set it in your per-repository or global configuration.

Answer (score 0):

After squash and closing the editor, you could amend the commit and change the text with a `#`.  For example:

```
git commit --amend -m "#1234 just a fix"
```